# How can I use JPopupMenu actionlistener inside a class constructor?

Tags: java, swing

I making a GUI that has a lot of buttons doing the exact same function, so I decided to make a special class of a `JButton` that does what I want which includes a `JPopupMenu` in it. However, an error comes with `show`, `getHeight` and `getWidth` that I don't understand: "The method `getHeight()` is undefined for the type new `ActionListener(){}`" and "The method `getWidth()` is undefined for the type new `ActionListener(){}`."

N.B: I copied the code from the `JPopupMenu`; I don't know how it works.

```java
public class MyButton extends JButton {
    
    JPopupMenu menu = new JPopupMenu("Menu");
    //create menu item
    JMenuItem a = new JMenuItem("A");
    JMenuItem b = new JMenuItem("B");
    JMenuItem c = new JMenuItem("C");
    JMenuItem d = new JMenuItem("D");

    public MyButton() {
        super();
        
        menu.add(a);
        menu.add(b);
        menu.add(c);
        menu.add(d);
        
        this.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                menu.show(this, this.getWidth() / 2, this.getHeight() / 2); //here is the error 
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: "however an error comes with show and getHight and getwidth that I don't understand" > What's the error? Can you edit your question and add that information.

Comment: Add the error you get. Otherwise everything you will get is guesswork. My guess from a quick glance is that it might be a divide by zero error on either height or width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating an anonymous instance of `ActionListener` and attempting to access the `MyButton` to which you adding the listener via `this` - but `this` is the `ActionListener`.  You should be able to use the source of the `ActionEvent` but you'll need to cast it.

```
JComponent source = (JComponent)ae.getSource();
menu.show(source, source.getWidth()/2, source.getHeight()/2);
```